# Adobe Premiere CC 2017 - decelerate video and audio (without excess of bass sound)?

Tags: premiere

I am a beginner at using Adobe Premier CC 2017. I have several videos that i want to slow down, especially the audio, to make the video easier to understand. I used the Speed/Duration effect and changed 100% to 75%, but that changed the pitch of the audio. It made it much lower with a lot more bass. So, I have tried applying an equalizer to correct the audio but I couldn't get it to sound normal.

I think you can change the speed of audio without changing the pitch in Adobe Audition, but I don't know how to use Audition, especially with needing to sync the audio with the video. Is there a way to do this just using Premiere?

Answer (score 2):

In the SPEED / DURATION menu that you can find in the context menu (RIGHTCLICK on a clip), check the MAINTAIN AUDIO PITCH checkbox. This will counteract the usual pitch shift resulting from the audio stretching.

Comment: Well done. Now can you show him how to TURN THE VOLUME DOWN?!

Comment: @stib what to you mean?

Comment: @stib edited. ;)

Comment: @MichaelLiebman CANT STOP WONT STOP, DONT BUST MY CHOPS

Answer (score 0):

To turn down the audio when, selected on the audio track hit g and set the gain to your choice. Or right click on the fx button and select audio gain and use the line on the audio clip